# Subtract two timestamps from two different columns that are in consecutive rows

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

So I have a pandas dataframe like this

```
   a  b
0  1  3
1  7  8
2  11 3
3  9  1
```

And I want to subtract the column b from the column a with the previous index, for example b[1] = 8 and a[0] = 1, then b[1] - a[0] = 7, that will be in c[1]

```
   a  b  c
0  1  3  -
1  7  8  7
2  11 3  -4
3  9  1  -10
```

How can I do it? Thanks for your time and help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.sub`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.sub.html) with shifted values by [`Series.shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html):

```
df['c'] = df['b'].sub(df['a'].shift())
print (df)
   a  b     c
0   1  3   NaN
1   7  8   7.0
2  11  3  -4.0
3   9  1 -10.0
```

For integers use [`integer na`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/integer_na.html) by convert to `Int64`:

```
df['c'] = df['b'].sub(df['a'].shift(1)).astype('Int64')
print (df)
    a  b     c
0   1  3  <NA>
1   7  8     7
2  11  3    -4
3   9  1   -10
```

Comment: Didn't know the shift function, really useful, thank you :D

Comment: @MiguelLebon - Thanks, glad to help. Don't forget to accept the answer, if it suits you! :)